# Sorting Algorithm in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, algorithm

I'm trying to sort my list using an algorithm. The list contains string arrays which holds date, titel and entry.

So the error message I am getting is this:

> Error CS0019  Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type
> 'string[]' and 'string[]'

I will not include all of my code, as it is not in English anyway.

```
List<string[]> loggBok = new List<string[]>();

        void nyttInlägg(string datum, string titel, string text) // När användaren anropar denna metoden från menyn, så kommer hans input
                                                                 // läggas in i vektorn. 
        {
            string[] anteckingar = new string[3] { "", "", "" };
            anteckingar[0] = datum;
            anteckingar[1] = titel;
            anteckingar[2] = text;
            loggBok.Add(anteckingar);

            
            
            bool isSorted = false;
            while (!isSorted)
            {
                isSorted = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < loggBok.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if ((loggBok[i]) > loggBok[i + 1])
                    {
                        string[] temp = loggBok[i + 1];
                        loggBok[i + 1] = loggBok[i];
                        loggBok[i] = temp;
                    }

                    i = i + 2;
                }
            }
```

So basically, every 3 element in the list will hold a stringarray with a date. This is the date that I want to organize. I believe I understand the logic behind the algorithm but I just cannot get the syntax right. I have checked other threads, some with similar problems but none that was 100%. As this is a school project it has to be an algorithm, thus I don't want to make it "easier" or more effective in anyway. Any ideas on how to overcome this horrible error message?

Comment: The most important tag is the programming language. Could you add it?

Comment: You should replace `if ((loggBok[i]) > loggBok[i + 1])` with `if ((loggBok[i][0]) > loggBok[i + 1][0]))` (also a closing parenthesis). That will compare the dates.

Comment: It should be logbok.add() rather than Add. Also logbok.size() instead of logbok.Size().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `>` greater than cannot be applied to type array or type string ( as mentioned in other answer comment)  - have a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators)

Each element in the list is an array of strings - with structure:

1. Data
2. Title
3. Text

So the following command will fails if `((loggBok[i]) > loggBok[i + 1]))` as you comparing two arrays with the operator `>`.

To retrieve the data you will have `loggBok[i][0]` which is a string.
You need to convert them to the correct type(eg. int) in order to use the comparison operator `>`.

I assumed the data is a type int -

```
                if (int.TryParse(loggBok[i][0], out int currentElement) && 
                    int.TryParse(loggBok[i + 1][0], out int nextElement) && 
                    currentElement > nextElement)
                {
                    string[] temp = loggBok[i + 1];
                    loggBok[i + 1] = loggBok[i];
                    loggBok[i] = temp;
                }
```

You can read about the TryParse [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was thinking it had to be solved in this way, couldn't get the syntax right tho. Thanks mate :D

Comment: @Maxkristiansson gald it works. Please consider upvoting and accepting an answer by clicking on that checkmark! Thanks

Comment: Done, but my upvote won't show as I have not voted for 15 answers yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- `if ((loggBok[i]) > loggBok[i + 1])` lacks a closing parenthesis
- The above attempts to compare *arrays*, while you just want to compare the dates. So you need to reference the date-entry in `loggBok[i]`:

  ```
  if ((loggBok[i][0]) > loggBok[i + 1][0]))
  ```
- The `i` index refers to arrays (triplets), so you should not increase it with three, but just with one, as it will go to the next triplet when you do `i++`, which is what you want. So remove `i = i + 2`, otherwise you skip some of these triplets.

Comment: Thank you mate, I added the language now which is C#. I made the changes, and the thing with reference makes sense but I am still getting the same error, or atleast now it's not saying string arrays, rather just string. 


CS0019 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'